# Error while building a static Linux binary (with musl-libc) that includes LuaJIT

Tags: gcc, lua, static-linking, luajit, musl

I've cloned the LuaJIT git repo and built it with:

```sh
make STATIC_CC="musl-gcc" BUILDMODE="static"
```

Then, I compiled a simple Lua "hello world" script into a C header file:

```
luajit -b test.lua test.h
```

test.h:

```c
#define luaJIT_BC_test_SIZE 52
static const unsigned char luaJIT_BC_test[] = {
27,76,74,2,10,45,2,0,3,0,2,0,4,54,0,0,0,39,2,1,0,66,0,2,1,75,0,1,0,20,72,101,
108,108,111,32,102,114,111,109,32,76,117,97,33,10,112,114,105,110,116,0
};
```

After that, I wrote a simple C wrapper by following the official example, test.c:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lualib.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

#include "test.h"

int main(void) {
    int error;
    lua_State *L = lua_open();
    luaL_openlibs(L);
    
    error = luaL_loadbuffer(L, (const char *) luaJIT_BC_test, luaJIT_BC_test_SIZE, "test") || lua_pcall(L, 0, 0, 0);
    if (error) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", lua_tostring(L, -1));
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    
    lua_close(L);
    return 0;
}
```

But when I try to build it, it crashes with an error:

```sh
$ musl-gcc -static -ILuaJIT/src -LLuaJIT/src -o test test.c -lluajit
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/12.1.0/libgcc_eh.a(unwind-dw2-fde-dip.o): in function `_Unwind_Find_FDE':
(.text+0x1953): undefined reference to `_dl_find_object'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It's related to libgcc, so I tried building everything with musl-clang, but still got the same error. Can someone explain what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out - I needed to build LuaJIT with `TARGET_XCFLAGS=-DLUAJIT_NO_UNWIND` like so:

```sh
make STATIC_CC="musl-gcc" BUILDMODE="static" TARGET_XCFLAGS=-DLUAJIT_NO_UNWIND
```

I guess this just disables C++ exceptions support, but I'm not sure what the real implications are. Seems to work fine, for now.